# How can I determine that a MAC address belongs to a VPN?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vpn, mac-address

While launching `ipconfig /all`, I can see the description and the physical address (MAC address) of the computers on my computer:

```
...
Description : Intel ...
Physical address : 48-4D-...
...
Description : Teamviewer VPN adapter
Physical address : 00-FF-...
```

From the description, I can see which MAC address belongs to my PC and which one belongs to the VPN adapter.

Can I also find this out without reading the description? Is there a way to distinguish VPN related MAC address from "real" ones? (A Windows API answer is preferred, if possible)

Comment: A VPN and Virtual machine are 2 different things. VPN = Virtual Private Network, VM (Virtual Machine) is software that emulates a pc in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are databases for the MAC addresses, for example from [Wireshark](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf).

Since my powershell is utterly bad, I just wrote a small program to iterate over this list and check for a match in the file by Wireshark.

You may check it out and modify as you want: https://github.com/maio290/MacChecker

If no vendor is found for the device, I guess you can assume that this device is a virutal one.